# 'MemoryMarshall' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm getting the error

'MemoryMarshall' is inaccessible due to its protection level

when I try to build my project.

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytesVectorBuffer =
            MemoryMarshal.Cast<sbyte, byte>(sbytesVectorBuffer);
```

That's the line where I get the error,
I've already imported `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` I understand it should be public so that it can be accesed but it's a method I can't modify as it is part of System.Runtime.InteropServices, when I click on the class to see the definition, it is

internal static class MemoryMarshal{...}

In other computers there isn't this problem, what could be causing the error?

I'm working on Visual studio 8.6.8 for Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a package reference to `System.Memory` ? i.e. `<PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.4" />`

Comment: What do you mean on other computers there isn't this problem? What happens when you click to see the definition there? Does it not say "internal"?